# Finishing transparent resin prints

Tags: resin

I am printing some resin models in transparent resin. They look quite good when they are coming out of the printer, but they later develop this white hazy look that even when removed with an IPA rinse appears to return. Here is an example:

[image]

As you can see this "hazy glaze" is almost as white as the underlying sheet of Scott paper.

How does one cure a transparent resin print to finish the best look for transparency?

Comment: Have you post-cured the prints? As in, hung them in a UV-light chamber? The haze is air-cured resin.

Comment: @Trish I think you got it, this was not chamber-cured. The [previous print](https://twitter.com/0xF2/status/1302634555136974848) was and does not show the whitening. How does one complete curing the surface so that it retains a wet, translucent look? There must be an oil or paint coat selection.

Comment: Also, if you want to write it up as an answer, so I can accept it. I assume the sequence is 1. IPA wash 2. UV curing. 3. whaterver finishing. 4. Done!

Comment: Looks like Step 3 is a pass of clearcoat. Formlabs has a nice [guide](https://formlabs.com/blog/3d-printing-transparent-parts-techniques-for-finishing-clear-resin/) to transparent printing that should apply.